# A character operand was found in the %EVAL function or %IF condition where a numeric operand is required

Tags: sas

```
%MACRO LIMIT_USAGE(NTABLENAME,PTABLENAME,NMNTH,PMNTH);
DATA LIMIT&NMNTH.; SET &NTABLENAME. &PTABLENAME.; BY SORTNO;    
LIMITCT&NMNTH. = %sysevalf(LIMITCOUNT + LIMITCT&PMNTH.) ;
DEBITAMT&NMNTH. = %EVAL(sum(input(DEBITAMT,8.2) , input(DEBITAMT&PMNTH.,8.2)));
RUN;
%MEND;
%LIMIT_USAGE(WORK.MT_2107, WORK.LIMIT2106,2107,2106);
```

I'm trying to sum 2 variables inside a macro function and its giving error: "A character operand was          found in the %EVAL function or %IF condition where a numeric operand is required. The condition was:
LIMITCOUNT + LIMITCT2106". I have tried using sysevalf and eval sum ().

Answer (score 3):

You don't need `%sysevalf` or `%eval` to compute a DATA Step expression.

Try

```
%MACRO LIMIT_USAGE(NTABLENAME,PTABLENAME,NMNTH,PMNTH);
  DATA LIMIT&NMNTH.; 
    SET &NTABLENAME. &PTABLENAME.; 
    BY SORTNO;    
    LIMITCT&NMNTH.  = LIMITCOUNT + LIMITCT&PMNTH. ;
    DEBITAMT&NMNTH. = sum(input(DEBITAMT,8.2) , input(DEBITAMT&PMNTH.,8.2));
  RUN;
%MEND;

%LIMIT_USAGE(WORK.MT_2107, WORK.LIMIT2106,2107,2106)
```

For the future case where you actually need to sum two macro variables outside the context of a DATA Step, use `%sysfunc(SUM(...))`